# How to check if there is a conflict in Day/Room/Start time/End time MySQL

Tags: mysql

So I have a table named tbl_fullsched. [Here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6qfr.jpg). As you can see, there are column named Day, Room, Start and End. They are all Varchar(). I want to compare all the data in this columns and display the data that has conflict. Like for example the "Monday" has two schedule in the same room but the time is conflicting with each other. Please help. Thanks

Comment: what you actually want to do??

Comment: First you should normalize your table and combine date and time to a DATETIME. Then it is very easy to calc with them.

Comment: @AjayMakwana - I want to to check if there is a conflict on day,room,time so that i can make a proper schedule with no conflict